# gcloud container create node pool with node taints command error

Tags: gcloud

What is wrong with the command?

```
gcloud container node-pools create abcxyz --zone europe-west1-b --cluster wordpress --machine-type g1-small --num-nodes 1 --node-taints=critical_assist=nfs_redis_heapster:NoExecute 
ERROR: (gcloud.container.node-pools.create) unrecognized arguments: --node-taints=critical_assist=nfs_redis_heapster:NoExecute (did you mean '--node-labels'?)
Usage: gcloud container node-pools create NAME [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --cluster | --disk-size | --enable-cloud-endpoints |
                         --help | --image-type | --machine-type |
                         --node-labels | --num-nodes | --scopes | --tags | -h
```

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud container node-pools create --help

I have found the command syntax here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/node-pools/create

Strangely I don't see anything in the help:
`gcloud beta container node-pools create --help | grep taint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 158.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.54
beta 2017.03.24
bq 2.0.24
core 2017.06.02
gcloud 
gsutil 4.26
kubectl 
Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

Once I ran `gcloud components update` this was fixed.